# Roblox teleporting to a place is restricted

Tags: roblox

I'm trying to make a part that when you touch it, it teleports you to a second place but it says
`Attempted to teleport to a place that is restricted`

For 2 hours i've been trying to figure it out but nothing on the internet seems to help
the code i used for teleport service:

```
local part = script.Parent
local teleport = game:GetService('TeleportService')

part.Touched:Connect(function(hit)
    if hit.Parent:FindFirstChild('HumanoidRootPart') then
        local player = game.Players[hit.Parent.Name]
        if player == nil then return end
        teleport:TeleportAsync(14633298425, {player})
        teleport:TeleportAsync(teleport, 14633298425, {player})

        local success, result = pcall(teleport.TeleportAsync, teleport, 14633298425, {player})
    end
end)
```